# Java: Comparing class simple name with String; renaming class with Eclipse ignores String

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to make a method whose result depends on the name of an inputted class

```
public boolean isOK (ProcessingTask pt){
if (pt.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("ProcessingTaskreplaceOUWithinThisItem")){
    return true;
}

return false;
}

public class ProcessingTaskreplaceOUWithinThisItem extends ProcessingTask {
```

but I think this is dangerous as the refactoring in Eclipse does not see that my String is in fact a class Name.

Is there a way to define "ProcessingTaskreplaceOUWithinThisItem" as being a 'class name' that will also get refactored?

Comment: One could do `pt.getClass() == MyClassName.class`, to detect an exact match.  Otherwise, `instanceof` is likely a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pt instanceof ProcessingTaskreplaceOUWithinThisItem.class
```

Comment: This one is actually a better way to solve the problem in general.

Comment: Of course, this will detect any *subclass* of the named class as well.

Comment: I now realise that I was suffering from smelly code. I cut my objects in a different way and decoupled them, now all is hunky-dory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the following way:

```
ProcessingTaskreplaceOUWithinThisItem.class.getSimpleName()
```